# Migration targets from Stellar

Tags: discussion, graduation, migration

Migration is the process of migrating questions that are off-topic at one Stack Exchange site to another site where they are on-topic.

While moderators may migrate a question to any other site, users with Close Vote privileges may select from a list of target sites.  If enough votes are given, the question is migrated without the intervention of a moderator.

Beta sites have only one permitted target site, that is the site's on Meta site.

Graduated sites may have a small list of targets.  We are shortly to graduate, and we will be able to add four target sites to this list.  The community should decide which site(s) should be added.

Please suggest target sites below.  One site per answer.  Vote on the suggestions.
After a reasonable time (6-8 weeks? ;) the relevant sites with the most upvotes (downvotes won't be counted) will be added to the list.  Choose wisely - there may actually be fewer than four relevant sites.

Comment: If the proposed Blockchain proposal gets off the ground, it could be a destination for generic questions. https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/126416/cryptocurrency-and-blockchain